# Send push notification with FCM to specific users using serverside functions with api

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm pretty new to firebase so I wanted to create a android app using firebase and React Native. I want to make an app that notifies me when a product is on offer. I would use a TextInput where I can write down the product and sends it to the firestore database.
Now let's say there are multiple users and they wait for different products to get on offer, how do I handle that. I know if a user logs into the app using google or email they have a userID or something like that.

My idea would be a server function that uses a api to get the product that are on offer from the website and then maybe compares it to every user if any values match with the offer.
But how do I proceed after that, how do I send the push notification to this users?

Comment: The question is a bit broad, are you asking [how to send a message with FCM?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) or [how to target a specific user with FCM?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+target+a+specific+user+with+FCM%3F)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud  Messaging push and deliver notification to the specified devices. You can push notifications through Firebase Console or Firebase Admin SDK.

You should use Firebase Admin SDK to push notifications when there're new offers depending on your business logic.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the users that Match the offer.

Comment: You need to save devices' push tokens for users in the database with other user-related information.  Later use those tokens to push notifications - https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/server-integration

Comment: Depending on business logic, Firebase Admin SDK will send  notification to those targeted users

Comment: That's a gratis exaple. Does the user needs to log in with Google or email?

Comment: Most firebase service work with authenticated users with Firebase authentication. If you already use your own authentication flow, it should cause some conflict.

Comment: I don't have more context about your project, and some of my recommendations should not be effective. If you like to chat for more, check my StackOverflow profile. I have contacts there.

Comment: Thanks, let's say the auser is authenticated in firebase via email or google auth. Should I run a script at firebase that checks for offers via api and then find the users in the database that look for a specific offer the api returned and finally send the notification to the user?

Comment: Yes, You can do that with Firebase Admin SDK which runs on your server, or deploy a cloud function on Firebase Server.